# jquery how to hide/show a language div?

Tags: jquery

In summary i have a slider with food images and a corresponding recipe div. In the recipe div i load german and english text at once but the english is set to display:none

How can i hide / show the right div based on a language selection?

```
<span id="lang">
    <span id="de" class="selectlang">
        <img  src="imgs/lang_de.jpg" alt="German" />
    </span> 
    | 
    <span id="en" class="selectlang">
        <img src="imgs/lang_en.jpg" alt="English" />
    </span>
</span>
```

and i tried the followin jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(window).load(function() {
        $('#recipes').orbit({
            timer: false,
            bullets: true,
            captions: true,
            afterSlideChange: textSlides
        });
        $('.selectlang').click(function() {
            var theId = "." + $(this).attr('id');
            alert(theId);
            $(theId).toggle().show();

        });
    });

    function textSlides() {
        var theId = "#d" + $(this).attr('id');
        $(theId).toggle().siblings().hide()
    } 
</script>
```

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trhy this [LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/corotchi/mVxSE/1/)

```
$('.selectlang').click(function() {
    var theId = "#" + $(this).attr('id');
    alert(theId);
    $("#lang span").show();

    $(theId).hide();


});
```

Comment: i am not trying to show/hide the div's with the flag images. But another div on the page <div id="dr2" style="display:none;">
  <span class="de">
  section 222 
  </span>
  <span class="en" style="display:none;">
  section 222 english
  </span>
 </div>

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
$(theId).toggle().show()
```

Is not right.

toggle() shows the element if it was hidden, hides it if it was visible.

Use show() for the selected language and hide() for the deselected one.

You've not shown us the markup for the English & German content divs. Can you confirm that the English one has a class of "en" and the German one a class of "de"?

Also, what's $(this) in textSlides()? Is it not "Recipes"? And the relevance of the #d prefix for theId in this method?

Comment: i have rewritten my code a bit but it doesn't seem to work in chrome and safari (FF5 is fine) [test file](http://www.nietverzonden.nl/test/) I tried the noconfict with no luck

Answer (score 0):

jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/jensbits/L7rx7/

Here's another fiddle which I think more closely matches what you want:

http://jsfiddle.net/jensbits/L7rx7/1/

Comment: great suggestion, going to try it out. Is there a way to have both language selectors visible?

Comment: I believe. Let me give it a try. Do you want any language as default showing or just the links?

Comment: hmm, it almost works. Problem is the slider hides/show the parent div's. I guess i need to set unique values for the div's?

Comment: If this worked for you, could you accept it as the answer? Thanks.